# EF Core cannot insert the value null into column with default value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have entity

```
public class Realtor
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime Registration { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int SubdivId { get; set; }
    public Subdiv Subdiv { get; set; }
}
```

and context with OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Realtor>(real => {
            real.Property<Guid>(p => p.Guid)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");

            real.Property<DateTime>(p => p.Registration)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

            real.HasOne(r => r.Subdiv)
            .WithMany(s => s.Realtors)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.SubdivId);
        });
```

I set default value for property Registration, but when I do an insert, I get Exception: cannot insert the value null into column Registration.

Comment: Why do you have a DateTime as Identity? That shouldn't be there, and why do you have both a Guid and an Id, and trying to make both the identity?

Comment: How can you be setting a `null` value for a non-nullable `DateTime` property? More likely, it is the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabasegeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute. I would imagine that `Identity` isn't defined for `DateTime` values, but only `int`.

Comment: Maybe
I try to remove

Comment: are you doing code first migrations?

Comment: @are you doing code first migrations@
Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, remove the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` for `Restration`. This could be the cause for your exception. If you don't want to make it nullable and want to set the value with your entity you could also:

```
public DateTime Restration { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Should work (I ain't got a VS 2015 here, so you have to test. Otherwise set the value for `Restration` in constructor.)

**update:** 
and remove at least this line

```
real.Property<DateTime>(p => p.Registration)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove

   ```
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   ```
2. Add a constructor in your Realtor class.

   ```
   public Realtor()
   {
     this.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
     this.Restration = DateTime.Now;
   }
   ```
3. And remove this from OnModelCreating

   ```
   real.Property<Guid>(p => p.Guid).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
   real.Property<DateTime>(p => p.Restration).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
   ```

Comment: It works! But I think that it is dubious decision. After all, it should work in the EF.

Comment: @Matthias Burger I'm sorry. I did not see your answer