# Are an Entity Framework object's properties with HasDefaultValue() automatically set to said default values at creation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, default-value

I guess that's a silly question, but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

I'm working with an EF Core entity, `BanalTable`. It has a property, `RegularString`, that I've set a default value in the `OnModelCreating()` method like so:

```
    z_etbTable.Property(t => t.RegularString).HasColumnName("BT_RegularString")
                                             .HasColumnType("varchar(25)")
                                             .HasDefaultValue("Hello solar system!")
                                             .HasMaxLength(25);
```

In my code, I create a `BanalTable` object with a simple

```
    BanalTable z_objKnownData = new BanalTable();
```

Debugging it shows that `z_objKnownData.RegularString` is `null`, while I'd expect it to be "Hello solar system!"

I've also tried to add it to the repository:

```
    z_dbcContext.BanalTableRepository.Add(z_objKnownData);
```

Both `z_objKnownData` and `z_dbcContext.BanalTableRepository.Local[0]` show a `null` value for `RegularString`.

It bears mentioning that for now, our database uses SQLServer 11, so it doesn't support default values. However, an upgrade might be in the works, so I'd like my code to be as ready as it can.

So... am I right to expect `RegularString` to be set to the default value I specified in `OnModelCreating()` ? Or is the default value supposed to be set in the data row when the repository's `SaveChanges()`, and only then set in the entity? (If so, what the blessed knowledge is the point with specifying a default value in `OnModelCreating()`?)

(I just found that the "Note:" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23657205/9256002) apparently answers my question, albeit sideways as it wasn't the main focus on the original question. Then I read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364084/ef-core-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-with-default-value) and they seem to imply that no, the default value isn't automatically set at object creation, but don't say it out loud. Also, both are more than five years old, a long time in computer science, and could now be outdated on that point.)

Comment: Usually such things rely on database's capabilities so if your DB doesn't support default values then most probably you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HasDefaultValue only applies to the database so the EF object wouldn't have that value. I think it's not working because `null` is a valid value for `string/VARCHAR`. If you set the field to "Not Null" by using the `IsRequired()` method then it may work as expected when saving to the database e.g.

```
z_etbTable.Property(t => t.RegularString).HasColumnName("BT_RegularString")
                                             .HasColumnType("varchar(25)")
                                             .HasDefaultValue("Hello solar system!")
                                             .HasMaxLength(25)
                                             .IsRequired();
```

Comment: OK, that's the straight answer I had come here for. I still don't see the point in specifying it in the code (except maybe to inform coders).

Comment: Specifying what, the "IsRequired" ?

Comment: No, the default value. Since EF goes to the database to fetch it anyway, the only reason I can think of for specifying it in the code with `HasDefaultValue()` would be as information for coders.

Comment: It's a default database value so if you don't provide a value for that field the default that you specify is saved to the DB

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand it fully, so here's a reworded question: what difference does it make whether `HasDefaultValue()` is specified or not?

Comment: ```HasDefaultValue()``` is used to specify a different default value for a field. If a row is inserted and no value/null is provided for the field that ```HasDefaultValue``` was called on, then the specified value will be stored to the Database. So in your case if null is passed as the value for BT_RegularString then ```"Hello solar system!"``` will be saved to the DB instead of ```null```.

Comment: All right, I think I'm starting to get it. But what if `BT_RegularString` is defined *in the database* with a default value of "Hello solar system!" and `RegularString` doesn't have the `HasDefaultValue()` specification? Is `"Hello solar system!" still saved to the DB?

Comment: You've kind of described an impossible scenario if I'm understanding correctly (and you're using code first). ```HasDefaultValue``` is how you tell the database what default value to use for ```BT_RegularString```.

Comment: We-ellll, the database definitely exists first in my project, and we're trying to slowly tack EFCore on. So I understand that in the case of a database-first scenario, `HasDefaultValue()` isn't needed in the `OnModelCreating()` method. (Other details, such as `HasMaxLength()` or `HasColumnName()`, range from useful to totally necessary.) Right?

Comment: Ah okay, ```HasDefaultValue()``` (as well as methods like ```HasMaxLength()```) is really for code first. A comment explaining that there is a default value of x for a given property is better than using ```HasDefaultValue()``` on a database first project. ```HasColumnName()``` is useful if you want to give properties a different name from the database fields.

Comment: At last we reach mutual understanding. Apologies for not making things clearer from the onset, and thanks a lot for sticking around through that long discussion!

Comment: No problem, I glad I could eventually help.